# Save multiple file uploaded by user inside database using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using asp.net and c# for making my app.I have two input type file field and user can upload multiple file for each input type file field.Suppose user selected two file for each input type file field.

I want to save those files inside database and local folder also.

index.aspx:

```
   <div class="col-md-6 bannerimagefile bmargindiv1">
     <label for="expcerti" accesskey="B"><span class="required">*</span> Experience Certificate Upload your experience certificate.</label>
    <ol id="expOl">
    <li>
    <div class="totalaligndiv">
    <div class="col-md-10 padding-zero bannerimagefilenew bmargindiv1"><input type="file" class="filestyle" data-size="lg" name="expcerti" ID="txtExpCert"  /></div><div class="col-md-2 padding-zero bmargindiv1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm exp-add" id="Expadd">+</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm exp-minus" id="Expminus" style="display:none;">-</button></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ol>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 bannerimagefile bmargindiv1">
    <label for="expcerti" accesskey="B"><span class="required">*</span> Publication/Papers Upload your publication/papers certificate.</label>
    <ol id="pubOl">
    <li>
    <div class="totalaligndiv">
    <div class="col-md-10 padding-zero bannerimagefilenew bmargindiv1">
    <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-size="lg" name="expcerti" id="expcerti"  /></div><div class="col-md-2 padding-zero bmargindiv1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pub-ppr " id="add">+</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pub-ppr-delete " id="minus" style="display:none;">-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ol>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="col-md-12 bmargindiv1">
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" class="button" ID="doctorDetails" OnClick="doctorDetails_Click" />
 </div>
    </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('click', '.exp-add', function () {
var i;
 if (sessionStorage.length == 0) {
      i = 1;
} else {
       i = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
}
$.getScript("js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js");
$('#expOl').append('<li><div class="totalaligndiv"><div class="col-md-10 padding-zero bannerimagefilenew bmargindiv1"><input type="file" class="filestyle" data-size="lg" name="expcerti" id="txtExpCert' + i + '" /></div><div class="col-md-2 padding-zero bmargindiv1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm exp-add " id="Expadd">+</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm exp-minus" id="minus" style="display:none">-</button></div><div class="clearfix"></div></div></li>');
 $(this).css('display', 'none');
 $(this).siblings("button.btn-danger").css('display', 'block');
 i++;
sessionStorage.setItem('id', i);
});
$(document).on('click', '.exp-minus', function () {
        $(this).closest("li").remove();
});
 $(document).on('click', '.pub-ppr', function () {
        var i;
  if (sessionStorage.length == 0) {
        i = 1;
   } else {
        i = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
   }
$.getScript("js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js");
$('#pubOl').append('<li><div class="totalaligndiv"><div class="col-md-10 padding-zero bannerimagefilenew bmargindiv1"><input type="file" class="filestyle" data-size="lg" name="expcerti" id="expcerti' + i + '" /></div><div class="col-md-2 padding-zero bmargindiv1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pub-ppr " id="Expadd">+</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pub-ppr-delete" id="minus" style="display:none">-</button></div><div class="clearfix"></div></div></li>');
$(this).css('display', 'none');
$(this).siblings("button.btn-danger").css('display', 'block');
i++;
sessionStorage.setItem('id', i);
});
 $(document).on('click', '.pub-ppr-delete', function () {
      $(this).closest("li").remove();
 });
 });
    </script>
```

I am using SQLServer for my database and explaining my design for Database below.

`Database name-Doctor`

`Table name-T_Doctor_Documents_Details`

```
ID       Document_Name     Document_File_Name
```

I have the above three field.`Document_Name` should contains which type of document it is and `Document_File_Name` should contain the file name.Please help me to save all files inside database and local folder as well  in code behind page (`i.e-index.aspx.cs`) after button click.